# GTK# Entry box disable tab moving focus

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I want to capture the tab key in a c# Gtk.SearchEntry element so that tab doesn't result in the element losing focus. I read that you can do this by returning false in the OnKeyPressEvent function. However, this doesn't work when overriding the function in the SearchEntry widget.

This does work if i override the Window's OnKeyPressEvent function but then the tab key is blocked for the entire window which isn't ideal...Here is my SearchEntry class:

```
internal class NoTabSearchEntry : SearchEntry
{
    protected override bool OnKeyPressEvent(EventKey evnt)
    {
        if (evnt.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("tab pressed");
            return false;
        }
        return base.OnKeyPressEvent(evnt);
    }
}
```

The "tab pressed" message does get output but the SearchEntry loses focus anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it...You need to return `true` from a handler for the key-press-event signal to prevent the default handling.

A couple other gotcha's. If you want to capture shift + tab you will need to check for the ISO_Left_tab key

```
if (evnt.Key == Key.Tab || evnt.Key == Key.ISO_Left_Tab)
```

I also wanted to capture the up/down arrow keys. For some reason those keypresses don't get passed to the `OnKeyPressEvent` handler; However, you can intercept them by adding to the `KeyPressEvent` attribute like this:

```
...
myEntryElement.KeyPressEvent += MyHandler;
...
[GLib.ConnectBefore]
private void MyHandler(object o, KeyPressEventArgs args)
{
    var evnt = args.Event;
    if (evnt.Key == Key.Down || evnt.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```